The legendre transform reaches the supremum it's defined with.
As is known, the Legendre transform g of a convex function f is defined as :
$g(p)=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} p(x)-f(x)$
With $p\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$.
However, it can be shown that the maximizer of the expression above exists and here lies my question.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex smooth function satisfying :
$\lim_{\| x\| \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\|x\|} = \infty.$
If $p\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, can you show that the superlevel sets :
{q, $p(q)-f(q)\geq c$} are compact ?
This would help me show that a supremum exists and is reached.

Why not just rewrite the problem first using inner product? Perhaps I am mistaken, but it seems to me that this replacement of the inner product with the syntactic sugar $p\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ is not much more than a hindrance.

I agree with Andrew's assessment of the notation choice. As a result, I will opt to call $g = f^{*}$ (the $*$ will denote the action of taking the Legendre transform of a given function) and any element $p$ in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ will have the representation of an inner product: $p(x) \equiv \langle x \, | \, p \rangle$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$ has itself as the dual space). Nevertheless, when a (in your particular case, smooth and convex) function satisfies
$$ \underset{ \| x \| \rightarrow +\infty }{\lim} \frac{f(x)}{\| x \|} = +\infty $$
it is called $\textbf{supercoercive}$ (note that this term is used for any function that satisfies that criteria). Furthermore we call $f$ $\textbf{coercive}$ if it satisfies the following:
$$ \underset{ \| x \| \rightarrow +\infty }{\lim} f(x) = +\infty. $$
Note that if $f$ is supercoercive, then it is automatically coercive.
Take
$$ p \in \textrm{int} \, \textrm{dom} \, f^{*} = \textrm{int} \{ u \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}) \, | \, f^{*}(u) < +\infty \}, $$
where $\textrm{int}$ denotes the topological interior, and set
$$ \textsf{F}_{p}(x) = f(x) - \langle x \, | \, p \rangle ~~~~(x \in \mathbb{R}^n). $$
Take $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}$ and observe that
$$ \frac{\textsf{F}_{p}(x)}{\| x \|} = \frac{f(x)}{\| x \|} - \left\langle \frac{x}{\| x \|} \, \middle| \, p \right\rangle \overset{\| x \| \rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} +\infty $$
since $\frac{x}{\| x \|}$ is a unit vector for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Thus, $\textsf{F}_{p}$ is supercoercive (and therefore coercive).
For any $c \in \mathbb{R},$ set
$$ \textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p} = \textsf{F}^{-1}_{p}((-\infty,c]) = \{ q \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, \textsf{F}_{p}(q) = f(q) - \langle q \, | \, p \rangle \leq c \}. $$ We claim that if $\textsf{F}_{p}$ is coercive, then the lower level sets $(\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p})_{c \in \mathbb{R}}$ are bounded. We give a proof of this result by contraposition.
Indeed, suppose that for some $c \in \mathbb{R},$ $\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p}$ is unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \| q_n \| = +\infty.$ Explicitly,
$$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) ~~ \textsf{F}_{p}(q_n) \leq c < +\infty ~~ \textrm{and}~~ \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \| q_n \| = +\infty. $$
Hence, $\textsf{F}_{p}$ is not coercive. In turn, the lower level sets $(\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p})_{c \in \mathbb{R}}$ are bounded. Also note that the lower level sets $(\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p})_{c \in \mathbb{R}}$ coincide with the superlevel sets
$$ \{ q \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, \langle q \, | \, p \rangle - f(q) \geq -c \} $$
which are the superlevel sets that you asked about (because $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, one may take the negative as an initial choice to get the desired sign you prefer).
Furthermore, the the lower level sets $(\textrm{lev}_{\leq c}\textsf{F}_{p})_{c \in \mathbb{R}}$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ This is clear since $f$ is continuous, and for any fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n},$ the mappings
$$ x \mapsto \langle x \, | \, y \rangle, ~~ x \mapsto \langle y \, | \, x \rangle $$
are continuous (either by assumption with $p \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ or by Theorem 4.6 in "Real and Complex Analysis" by Walter Rudin - Page 78). Thus, the superlevel sets are compact (compactness in $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with being closed and bounded).
$\textbf{Remark}:$

In this solution, I have restated a portion of a proposition in "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" (2nd Edition) by Bauschke and Combettes (Proposition 11.12).
I added a minor adjustment to the set from which we take our dual element $p.$ I believe that this is necessary for the coercivity condition (Legendre transform is a supremum so it could be infinite). Perhaps it is not required for such a set to be compact, so anyone with a proof that does not need this, please add your solution.

